# Creating an "allowed-users" list in Next.Js while implementing Google Auth

Tags: java, reactjs, json, security, next.js

I am fairly new to Next and React, and I really don't know a whole lot about backend anything except very basic knowledge for how models and using the data works.

Ok, so far the method I have used is working. However, I went to the client side and the login.js file obviously showed the JSON file items in the allowed-users.json because I imported it and checked the array for the allowed users. The logic works and only the emails on the list can login with Google Auth.

This is not a major issue because the app idea I am coming up with is not supposed to be a site pushed to production with a lot of publicity, but I still would like to know something I could do to make this secure to learn.

I am open to any suggestions, or any correction on anything I am doing that is not good practice. I am here to learn. What I did in this code is just a test to get it to work, and the whole project is just to test out using the NextAuth with Google to give users permissions on the site to implement an Admin, Employee, Client system for the accounts.

My Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSession, signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";
import GoogleButton from "react-google-button";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import allowedUsers from "./api/allowed-users.json";

const Login = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  console.log(session);

  if (!session) {
    return (
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center content-center h-full">
        <div>
          <GoogleButton onClick={() => signIn()} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  if (session && allowedUsers.includes(session.user.email) ) {
    router.push("/account");
  } else {
    const exitLogin = () => signOut();
    exitLogin();
  }
};

export default Login;
```

I have tried reading Next documentation on handling JSON and also API calls, but like I said, I am fairly new to this. I come from old school HTML / CSS / with simple JavaScript for simple sites. I am trying to broaden my knowledge to learn how to develop apps and sites that are viable nowadays.

If anyone has good documentation I should read please link it, or if you know a tutorial somewhere I can read through or watch that covers a topic similar to this.

Thanks!

Knight

Comment: From where `allowedUser` coming from? From the server or you have hardcoded json file there which I'm assuming is the case.

Comment: its in the Next pages/api folder. I checked in the sources in dev tools and its hidden like its supposed to be. But of course its parsed in my login.js to show the array